# Music discs have do not get quieter by distance in my Minecraft 1.14.4 mod

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm having trouble implementing my custom music discs into the game. Everything with the actual item (texture, model, plays music in jukebox, etc.) works properly however, when the music is playing, no matter where you are in the world, you can hear it. I would like to make it so that my music discs have limited distance like the vanilla discs.

Here is my registration of the item (only one of the music discs, I removed all other items for the sake of convenience):

```
@SubscribeEvent
public static void registerItems(final RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event) {

    event.getRegistry().registerAll
    (
        //All other items
        ModItems.music_disc_song = new ModMusicDiscItem(15, new SoundEvent(location("song")), (new Item.Properties().group(MODGROUP).maxStackSize(1).rarity(Rarity.RARE))).setRegistryName(location("music_disc_song"))
    );
}
```

Here is my initialization of the disc in ModItems:

```
//All other items
public static Item music_disc_song;
```

Here is the class ModMusicDiscItem:

```
public class ModMusicDiscItem extends MusicDiscItem {

    public ModMusicDiscItem(int id, SoundEvent sound, Item.Properties prop) {
        super(id, sound, prop);
    }
}
```

And here is my sounds.json:

```
{
    "song": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "censoredid:music_discs/song",
                "volume": 0.05,
                "stream": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Again, playing the music works properly, however, the volume does not decrease with distance. This code worked for 1.13.2 (with of course changing MusicDiscItem to ItemRecord), but does not in 1.14.3 or 1.14.4. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I tried googling the issue and ran into your other thread on minecraftforge. oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file needs to be recorded in mono, and then transferred to a .ogg. Mono allows the game to edit sound based off perspective alone, while stereo (what you're dealing with), plays the audio file as just that, an audio file.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/230224/playsound-globally-on-server) states that the sound has console commands that can affect it; it seems to suggest that by entering a value for **"volume"** other than zero in your sounds.json file may cause it to be global.
I can't experiment with it now, but try removing the volume variable, or setting it to equal the value 0.

If that doesn't work, try the server commands from the other answer.

Comment: Tried removing and changing volume to 1, neither fix the issue. I also tried the other solution, and it did not work either

Comment: @kaydogz change the volume to 0, not to 1.

Comment: Oh shit I misread that. As soon as I get home I’ll try it and let you know if it works

Comment: @kaydogz any luck?

Comment: I’m trying to do it but for some reason no matter what volume I set it to, it does not play the music at all. Instead, it just says “unable to do play soundEvent”

Comment: I fixed the soundEvent issue, however, volume 0 does not work